# Angular2 - Deploy Package for final user

Tags: angular, deployment

I have an **Angular2** application that works properly and its ready to move in production.

The deploy must be done on **over than 30 client**.

For each client, it is necessary to **modify the parameter** that contains the webapi used in the application.

The problem is that who will install the application on the clients doesn't know anything of anulgar2, this means that **he can't edit the properly file and run ng build command etc**...

So how can I work around this situation ?

Thanks to rupport

Comment: what kind parameter will be different from each client ?

Comment: just the webapi url

Comment: Do you use jenkins or anything for deploying? How do they deploy things?

Comment: No I don't use jerkins, they should just copy the folder in the webserver root and edit a json config file that contain the webapi url. Stop.
They don't have to use ancular client to create the dist... Just copy,paste and edit the webapi url

Comment: then u have to create a batch file or shell script which accepts this url and replaces in your property file.it can trigger other things as needed ..Then can just click on the sh file or bat file and give the value